# QST: What is the canonical way to convert a column of type string[pyarrow] to boolean within a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm wanting to convert string data which is indeed boolean (or null) e.g. values are y / n / NA, or true / false / NA, or even a mix of these.

When using pandas with `numpy` backend as default, conversion from string data to boolean works smoothly:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["true", None, "false"]})
assert df.dtypes["col1"] == "object", df.dtypes["col1"]
# convert to boolean
df["col1"] = df["col1"].replace({'true': True, 'false': False}).astype(bool)
assert df.dtypes["col1"] == bool, df.dtypes["col1"]
```

However, when using the pyarrow backend (in my use case, I was actually using `pd.read_parquet` with `dtype_backend` - but I set the type explicitly in the example below):

```py
df_pyarrow = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": ["true", None, "false"]}, dtype="string[pyarrow]"
)
assert df_pyarrow.dtypes["col1"] == "string", df_pyarrow.dtypes["col1"]
df_pyarrow["col1"] = (
    df_pyarrow["col1"]
    .replace({'true': True, 'false': False})  # fails at this step
    .astype(bool)
)
assert df_pyarrow.dtypes["col1"] == "bool[pyarrow]", df_pyarrow.dtypes["col1"]
```

but this fails at the .replace() because pyarrow complains, rightly!, that `True` and `False` are not valid values for a string[pyarrow]: `TypeError: Scalar must be NA or str`.

I have found that this method works:

```py
df_pyarrow["col1"] = df_pyarrow["col1"] == "true"

assert df_pyarrow.dtypes["col1"] == "bool[pyarrow]", df_pyarrow.dtypes["col1"]
```

However:

- `df_pyarrow.info()` still says `col1` is `string[pyarrow]`
- this method isn't as flexible: what if there were multiple values for True/False

What is the canonical way to convert a column of type `string[pyarrow]` to boolean within a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

You should use map instead of replace

```py
df_pyarrow["col1"] = (
    df_pyarrow["col1"]
    .map({'true': True, 'false': False})
    .astype("bool[pyarrow]")
)
```

It works with numpy because an array of string in numpy is actually and array of object. So you can replace strings with booleans, they are still objects.

With pandas and the pyarrow backend, it is more strict about type.

Comment: Thank you - this looks like a solution to my specific example, and in general. Do you have a reference to back up that this should be the canonical way of doing a string rename in pandas?

Comment: ~the thing that gives me pause is that, if you run `df_pyarrow.info()` you'll still see col1 listed as `string[pyarrow]` (if you `df_pyarrow["col1"].dtype` you see it is `bool[pyarrow]` though... as with my `==` solution)~ Sorry scratch that, have rerun and it updates correctly! Would be great to get a reference (or even link to usage) for this to show it's the generally accepted (if not canonical) way of doing things.

Comment: I don't think there is a canonical/generally accepted of doing things in pandas. It's a very open API and it depends on what you are trying to optimise for (performance, readability, idempotence, correctness...). Also what you are trying to do is not renaming strings (which you would do with `str.replace`). You are trying to match string which is typically done using regular expressions (`str.match`). See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html

Answer (score 1):

If I use:

```
df = (pd.read_parquet('data.parquet', dtype_backend='pyarrow')
        .astype({'col1': 'bool[pyarrow]'}))
```

I get:

```
>>> df
    col1
0   True
1   <NA>
2  False

>>> df.dtypes
col1    bool[pyarrow]
dtype: object

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype        
---  ------  --------------  -----        
 0   col1    2 non-null      bool[pyarrow]
dtypes: bool[pyarrow](1)
memory usage: 130.0 bytes
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['true', None, 'false']})
df.to_parquet('data.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

Comment: Thank you

```python
df_pyarrow["col1"] = (
    df_pyarrow["col1"]
    .astype('bool[pyarrow]')
)
```

Fixes the error in my specific example - but would this work with a mix of strings e.g. ["yes", "true", None, "no", "false]?